# R-- Extract specific text and the subsequent text/numbers

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have a column with text strings in it, and I would like to extract not just a specific string, but also the string or number/s following this specified string. What is a good solution for this?

In the example below- I would like to create a column "extract" and `str_extract` the words "lot" and "unit" AND also extract the subsequent numbers following this text.

| id | notes | extract |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | LOT 56, STRATA TITLE, 56/SP77100, | LOT 56 |
| 2 | 18/SP71866, COMMERCIAL, 17/SP71866, lot 18 | lot 18 |
| 3 | unit 9; 3R/PS732002 | unit 9 |
| 4 | V1602 F63, Section 8 Block 68 Unit 3 | Unit 3 |

Have looked at a lot of regex code but nothing helpful to find how to extract subsequent values from the specified target text string.

Tried this so far from another StackOverflow problem-

```
 result <- table %>% 
  mutate(extract = str_extract(notes, "(?lot\\s)\\W\\s?\\d+\\")) %>%
  mutate(lot = str_squish(lot))
```

Comment: If my answer did not solve your problem please consider updating the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```r
str_extract(notes, "(?i)\\b(?:lot|unit)\\W*\\d+")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dA9WnC/1).

*Details*

- `(?i)` - case insensitive flag
- `\b`  - a word boundary
- `(?:lot|unit)` - either `lot` or `unit`
- `\W*` - any zero or more non-word chars
- `\d+` - one or more digits.

R test:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- data.frame(notes=c("LOT 56, STRATA TITLE, 56/SP77100,","18/SP71866, COMMERCIAL, 17/SP71866, lot 18","unit 9; 3R/PS732002", "V1602 F63, Section 8 Block 68 Unit 3"))
df %>% 
+   mutate(extract = str_extract(notes, "(?i)\\b(?:lot|unit)\\W*\\d+"))
                                       notes extract
1          LOT 56, STRATA TITLE, 56/SP77100,  LOT 56
2 18/SP71866, COMMERCIAL, 17/SP71866, lot 18  lot 18
3                        unit 9; 3R/PS732002  unit 9
4       V1602 F63, Section 8 Block 68 Unit 3  Unit 3
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `regmatches`

```
transform(
  df,
  extract = unlist(regmatches(notes, gregexpr("\\b(lot|unit)\\s\\d+", notes, ignore.case = TRUE)))
)
```

gives

```
  id                                      notes extract
1  1           LOT 56, STRATA TITLE, 56/SP77100  LOT 56
2  2 18/SP71866, COMMERCIAL, 17/SP71866, lot 18  lot 18
3  3                        unit 9; 3R/PS732002  unit 9
4  4       V1602 F63, Section 8 Block 68 Unit 3  Unit 3
```

## Data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = 1:4, notes = c("LOT 56, STRATA TITLE, 56/SP77100", 
"18/SP71866, COMMERCIAL, 17/SP71866, lot 18", "unit 9; 3R/PS732002",
"V1602 F63, Section 8 Block 68 Unit 3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-4L))
```